# Testing boolean type with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am writing test cases using `JUnit` to generate `Cobertura Report` with `Maven`.

Here is the method which  needs to be tested but I am not sure how to make it work the parameters because all it takes is reference types.

```
public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
    return type == RetrieveBillingResponse.class && !mediaType.isWildcardType()
            && !mediaType.isWildcardSubtype()
            && mediaType.isCompatible(MediaType.valueOf("text/xml"));
}
```

What I have done so far is

```
public class TestRetrieveBillingResponseXMLReader {

private Type type;
private Class<?> clazz;
private MediaType mediaType;
private Annotation[] annotations;

@Test
public void testIsReadable() {

    mediaType = new MediaType();
    mediaType = MediaType.valueOf("text/xml");

    RetrieveBillingResponseXMLReader xmlReader = new RetrieveBillingResponseXMLReader();
    boolean expected = xmlReader.isReadable(clazz, type, annotations, mediaType);
    assertTrue(expected);
}
}
```

I am getting AssertionError.

Can someone tell me how to make it work?

Comment: because xmlReader.isReadable is returning false

Comment: If I do assertFalse the test passes but 'Cobertura' won't recognize it because this is not expected.

Comment: Debug your isReadable method during the test and check which condition make return whole method as false. Then you should try to understand why it happens.